# Scopes and the methods those do the same thing

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

I want to define 2 methods in Mongoid: expensive? and the scope for it. Here is what I'm doing:

```
class MyItem
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # it could find expensive and cheap items depending of is_expensive parameter
  scope :expensive, ->(is_expensive = true) do
    if is_expensive
      where(:expensive?)
    else
      not_in(:expensive?)
    end
  end

  def expensive?
    price >= 10 # $10
  end
end
```

So I want to able to find items the following ways:

```
  MyItem.expensive #find all expensive ones
  MyItem.where(:expensive?) #the same as above
  MyItem.first.expensive? #check if it's expensive
  items.expensive # items is the collection of MyItem
```

They don't work. For instance, `MyItem.where(:expensive?)` says `undefined method each_pair for :expensive?:Symbol`

**Especially** I want to figure out how to do the method or scope which will work as an **instance method** (not a class method) - `items.expensive`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have experience with Mongoid, so the answer might not be fully correct, but to me it seems you are mixing two things: database querying, and calling methods on an instance.

They are two separate things and can not be intermixed. For example:

```
def expensive? 
  price >= 10
end
```

...is not a database query method. You're simply looking at an instance variable and checking if it's >= 10. Therefore you can't use this method in database queries since it's not a query construct.

But to make it work should not be too hard. All you need to change is this:

```
scope :expensive ... do
  is_expensive ? where(:price.gte => 10) : where(:price.lt => 10)
end
```

The argument to `where` must always be a [Mongoid query expression](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#where). It cannot be something else.

Now your setup should work. You can ask everything you need:

```
MyItem.expensive          # Returns a collection of expensive items
MyItem.first.expensive?   # Calls the instance method. Returns true or false
items.expensive           # Returns all expensive items in the collection
```

However this is will not work:

```
MyItem.where(:expensive?)
```

Because `:expensive?` is not a valid query expression, which is what is always needed as an argument to `where`.